# Python: Compress file

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python. I want to compress a file with password. I know there are some compress-libraries like zigfile, patool, tarfile, gzip and so on. But I couldn't find a library with I can compress a file with password. For example you can compress a file with password with winrar. I also know there is a [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.2) for rar. Well I think you need the rar-program on your system. And this is a problem. There is a dependency.

In Short: What I want?
- Compress a file (for example in *.zip-file oder whatever)
- Compress with password
- if its possible: Compress in an encrypted file
- extract this compressed file with password

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195747/python-code-to-create-a-password-encrypted-zip-file/2366917#2366917

Comment: Hallo helloV, he solution with 7-Zip - then create another problem. Because a user he uses my software he needs also the software named 7-zip, right? My software is also dependents on 7-zip. My program can't create a zip file without 7zip. I thought there a solution without dependence. For example, I don't need Winzip for creating a zi file with the library named zipfile, right? And exactly this solution were fine.

Comment: CORRECTED COMMENT: Hello helloV, the solution with 7-Zip - this creates another problem. Because a user he uses my software he needs also the software named 7-zip, right? My software is also dependents on 7-zip. My program can't create a zip file without 7zip. I thought there is a solution without dependence. For example, I don't need Winzip on my system for creating a zip file with the library named zipfile, right? And exactly this solution would be fine.