# Create encrypted zip files from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, zip

How can I create encrypted zip files for everything in a list? I'd like to use 'zip -er (list item).zip (list item)/' after the directory is created.

```
import os

list = ['Folder1', 'Folder2']

for item in list:
    if os.path.exists(item):
        print True
    else:
       os.makedirs(item)
       print "[+]Creating %s Directory" % (item)
```

Comment: Which encryption methods have you looked at?  What type of serialisation are you using?  Pickle?  YAML? JSON? XML? Your own?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python code to create a password encrypted zip file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195747/python-code-to-create-a-password-encrypted-zip-file)

Comment: I'm hoping to use the native encryption on my macbook using the zip command with an '-e' flag.