# "File path contains null characters" when loading a file from a .zip with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game which includes image, text, and audio files located in a password-protected .zip. I'm trying to use `pygame.image.load` and show the image like this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pygame
import pyganim
import sys

pygame.init()
root = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('image load test')



archive = ZipFile("spam.zip", 'r')
mcimg = archive.read("a.png", pwd=b'onlyforthedev')

mc = pygame.image.load(mcimg)

anime = pyganim.PygAnimation([(mcimg, 100),
                              (mcimg, 100)])
anime.play()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    windowSurface.fill((100, 50, 50))
    anime.blit(root, (100, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is the error I get from this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\VERY IMPORTANT FOR GAME DISTRIBUTION\few.py", 
  line 41, in <module>
  mc = pygame.image.load(mcimg)
  pygame.error: File path '�PNG


  ' contains null characters
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python code to create a password encrypted zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195747/python-code-to-create-a-password-encrypted-zip-file)

Comment: Your code is already doing exactly what you asked how to do: `mcimg = archive.read("a.png", pwd=b'onlyforthedev')`. So… what's the problem you're asking about?

Comment: I just added the error message

Answer (score 1):

The function [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) can load an image from a file source. You can pass either a filename or a Python file-like object.

But, actually you give the image bytes.

To fix that you can wrap your bytes in an `io.Bytes` instance and use it as a file-like object:

```
import zipfile
import io

with zipfile.ZipFile("spam.zip", 'r') as archive:
    mcimg = archive.read("a.png", pwd=b'onlyforthedev')

mc = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(mcimg))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped for the image part. But what about the audio and text files? can they be accessed the same way?

Comment: @ClaraDocej, sure. For instance, you can use [pygame.mixer.music.load](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) to load the music for playback…

Comment: tried doing that exactly, but it crashed all of python.

Comment: @ClaraDocej, it’s better to post another question with a sample of your code and the trace back. It’s easier to diagnose and answer.