# Python code to create password protected zip in-memory for HttpResponse

Tags: python, memory, io, zip, 7zip

I would like to generate a password-protected Zip file for my csv data in memory and return to webpage via Django HttpResponse.
So far I can generate plain zip file to HttpResponse as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import io, csv, zipfile, subprocess
#...

# write csv in buffer
buffer_string_csv = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer_string_csv)
writer.writerow(['foo','bar'])

# write zip in buffer
buffer_zip = io.BytesIO()
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer_zip, 'w')
zip_file.writestr('foobar.csv', buffer_string_csv.getvalue())
zip_file.close()

# return zip file as response 
response = HttpResponse(buffer_zip.getvalue())
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip-compressed'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foobar.zip"'
return response
```

The problem is the password-protecting part for the Zip file.
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195747/), I learned password-protecting Zip file can be created via 7-Zip utility.

```
subprocess.run(['7z', 'a', '-pPASSWORD', '-y', 'password_foobar.zip'] + ['foobar.csv'])
```

Is it possible to do that in-memory?
Or any alternatives that don't require saving intermediate files into the filesystem?