# File encryption with Python

Tags: python, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt files (.zip, .doc, .exe, ... any type of file) with Python?

I've looked at a bunch of crypto libraries for Python including pycrypto and ezpycrypto but as far as I see they only offer string encryption.

Comment: Related: [Create an encrypted ZIP file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/create-an-encrypted-zip-file-in-python)

Comment: In Python 2, strings are really byte-strings, so you can just read in the file as binary, encrypt it, then write as binary.

Comment: Ugh.. how come I couldn't think that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In Python versions prior to version 3.0, the [`read` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) of a [`file` object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) will return a string, provide this string to the encryption library of your choice, the resulting string can be written to a file.

Keep in mind that on Windows-based operating systems, the default mode used when reading files may not accurately provide the contents of the file. I suggest that you be [familiar with the nuances of file modes and how they behave on Windows-based OSes](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1):

You can read the complete file into a string, encrypt it, write the encrypted string in a new file. If the file is too large, you can read in chunks.

Every time you `.read` from a file, you get a string (in Python < 3.0).