# Setting a password with python's zipfile module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-zipfile

When using the python module `zipfile`, for some reason I don't know I can't set a password for an archive created.

When trying to unzip following empty zip archive, I can do so without prompting a password..

Here is my code, what's wrong?

```
import zipfile  
with zipfile.ZipFile("1.zip","w") as zip:
    zip.setpassword("1234")
```

Comment: Isn't the password only needed to read the files in the archive? If the archive has no files, nothing requires the password.

Comment: @user2357112: It happens also for non empty zip files

Answer (score 2):

From documentation for [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module

> It supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it currently cannot create an encrypted file.

Comment: See [this quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/create-an-encrypted-zip-file-in-python) for more on other ways to do this.

Comment: So what is the `setpassword` method for?

Comment: For extracting decrypted files