# zipfile module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to create password protected zip file using `zipFile` module?
I tried zipfile.setpassword() and it doesn't work.

If it's not possible using this module please suggest alternative way

Thanks

Comment: I think the "extract" gives it away...

Comment: The module only supports reading password-protected zipfiles currently.

Comment: Look here or further discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/create-an-encrypted-zip-file-in-python