# suppress deprecation in python

Tags: python, deprecated

so - I'm using a library pyminizip - which is the only way I've found to create a password protected zip file.   When I use it I get a **deprecationwarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN will be required for '#' formats.**

now, I have no control over that library, no ability to fix it - nor do I seem to have an easy alternative to using it - and it works fine.  So the deprecation warning adds zero value to me - but it interferes with the UI of my tool - as it appears on stdout.    Is there any way to suppress it/make it go away?

the way I'm calling it is:

```py
   import pyminizip
   pyminizip.compress_multiple( [ prod_report ], [], f"C:/temp/report{name}.zip", "Password", 9 )
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's a bug in the library rather than a bug with how you use it?

Comment: In the former case the easiest way would be to contact the library author and tell them to fix the bug, **or** find a more up-to-date fork and use it, **or** make one yourself. Find convoluted way to suppress the output (redirect `sys.stderr` might work) is not a good idea.

Comment: Anyway post a [example] for how to create the error message.

Comment: You can redefine stdout to be a stream of your own making that filters its input and outputs what makes it through the filter to stdout.  Then you can look for and remove just this one message. - or just redirect to /dev/null if you don't need any output to show.

Comment: adam - no I'm not - but either way - I want the warning to go away :)

Comment: If the python script is for one platform only, you could simply use a subprocess instead. Otherwise you could use `contextlib.redirect_stdout` or `redirect_stderr` to prevent it from printing

Comment: adam - zipfile doesn't allow you to write a password protected zip file - only read

Comment: @DarrenOakey ah you're so right -- my mistake!

Comment: And what Python version are you using? 3.8 or 3.9?

Comment: Looks like someone already filed an issue on the repository. https://github.com/smihica/pyminizip/issues/34

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon (does it really work in this case? This is raised by a C API usage)

Comment: The double-duplicate of the linked question above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/create-an-encrypted-zip-file-in-python has several "other libraries" (workarounds in this case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/879249/15213571

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519680/248616), I just put this line on top of my starting code

```
import warnings ; warnings.warn = lambda *args,**kwargs: None
```