# How to Create Password Protected Zip file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to zip a text file with password how can i achive it

for example

```
filename = "./data.txt"
password = "1234"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an encrypted ZIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-an-encrypted-zip-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can  try with pyminizip module

```
# import module 
import pyminizip 
  
# input file 
input_file = "./data.txt"
pre = None
  
# zip file save path 
output_file = "./data.zip"
  
# set password 
password = "1234"
  
# compress level 
compress_lvl = 5
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    # compressing file 
    pyminizip.compress(input_file, None, output_file, password, compress_lvl)
```

Comment: glad it was useful