# How to create password protected csv or ZIP archive in python

Tags: python, csv, file, zip, fastapi

```
async def get_report(id):
    try:
        data = await collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(id)}).to_list(None)
        if data:
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
            directory = Path("/")
            file_name = "abcd.csv"
            file_path = directory / file_name
            df1.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
            password = "1234"
            zip_file_path = directory / (file_name + ".zip")
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
                zf.setpassword(password.encode('utf-8'))
                zf.write(file_path, arcname=file_name)
            response = FileResponse(zip_file_path, media_type='application/zip', filename=file_name+".zip")
            return response
            #json_data = {'file':str(zip_file_path)}
            #response = requests.post(url,json=json_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is my code, here i am trying to create csv of data frame and send file in email(code is not there here, but csv is sending in mail(its working)) file is downloading csv and zip both. but is not password protected( return response) here, is it possible to do, if yes what i am missing here.

Comment: The `setpassword` method is only for reading, not writing (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword). See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-an-encrypted-zip-file) for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin zipfile module does not support writing password-encrypted files (only reading) see [docs][1] you could use pyminizip:

```
pip install pyminizip
```

```
import pyminizip


async def get_report(id):
    try:
        data = await collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(id)}).to_list(None)
        if data:
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
            directory = Path("/")
            file_name = "abcd.csv"
            file_path = directory / file_name
            df1.to_csv(file_path, index=False)# remove if you dont want to save .csv file as well
            password = "1234"
            zip_file_path = directory / (file_name. + ".zip")
            pyminizip.compress(file_path, None, zip_file_path, password, 0)
            response = FileResponse(zip_file_path, media_type='application/zip', filename=file_name+".zip")
            return response
            #json_data = {'file':str(zip_file_path)}
            #response = requests.post(url,json=json_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword
```

Comment: refer this link  for import:  https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/

pyminizip.compress(str(file_path), "", str(zip_file_path), password, 0)

Comment: How to achieve if we need Excel instead if zip/ csv