# Why the ZipFile python library does not enforce passwords if ZipCrypto encryption is set?

Tags: python, python-zipfile, system.io.compression.zipfile

I am trying to create a zip file using DEFLATED compression and ZipCrypto encoding. The test is only trying to uncompress the zip file created using the Win11 Extractor tool. I used the code below to generate the zip file, which was created with success, but when I try to extract it, no password is being asked by any decompress software you can imagine. Why?

```
def zip_directory_with_password(directory_path, zip_file_path, password):
    # Create a password-protected Zip file with ZipCrypto encryption
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True) as zip_file:
        # Set the password for ZipCrypto
        zip_file.setpassword(password.encode('utf-8'))

        # Walk through the directory and add all files and directories to the Zip file
        for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                arcname = os.path.relpath(file_path, directory_path)
                zip_file.write(file_path, arcname)
                print(f"Added file: {arcname}")

            for subfolder in subfolders:
                folder_path = os.path.join(foldername, subfolder)
                arcname = os.path.relpath(folder_path, directory_path)
                zip_file.write(folder_path, arcname)
                print(f"Added folder: {arcname}")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an encrypted ZIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-an-encrypted-zip-file)

Comment: `.setpassword("yourpassword")` is for extracting, not for creating a zip file

Comment: thanks for your reply. If setpassword is only for extract how do I zip a bunch of files protected by a password using ZipCrypto encode ?

Comment: Did you check the duplicate in my first comment? And I would advise AGAINST using ZipCrypto as it is week and vulnerable to known plaintext attacks that could easily be exploited

Comment: I know but I do not have option. This software must create a zip for an old equipment and is only able to uncompress zip encoded with ZipCryto. That's why I cannot use AES.